# WPF: применение унаследованных стилей к унаследованным элементам

Tags: wpf, xaml

Элемент `CustomToggleButton` унаследован от стандартного `ToggleButton`:

```
class CustomToggleButton : ToggleButton {

    static CustomToggleButton() {
        CustomToggleButton.DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(CustomToggleButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomToggleButton)));
    }

    // ...   
}
```

`ToggleButtonCommon` - основные стилевые настройки для `CustomToggleButton`, а `InGroupToggleButton` - унаследованный от него стиль:

```
<Style  x:Key="ToggleButtonCommon"
        TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomToggleButton}" 
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">

        // ...
</Style>

<Style x:Key="InGroupToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource ToggleButtonCommon}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="5 5 5 0" />
</Style>
```

Оказалось, что к элементу `CustomToggleButton` можно применить лишь `ToggleButtonCommon`, но не `InGroupToggleButton` и никакой другой производный стиль.

В чём причина данного явления и возможно ли применить к `CustomToggleButton` унаследованные стили?

Comment: Наследование принципиально нужно? Просто стилизовать элемент нельзя?

Comment: @Андрей, с этим вопросом окей, нужно просто `"{x:Type local:CustomToggleButton}"` было добавить :)

Answer (score 0):

В определение стиля следует добавить `TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomToggleButton}"`.